# The address on the variables are not changing

Tags: c

I am trying to work with the address of variables. However, the variables have the same address at every run. Since I am moving between different addresses why is the variable address still the same? When I try to copy the result it still gives me the same value.

```
typedef struct Node{
    char *color; /* Color of the light */
    int **details; /*holds the brightness and size*/
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

Node * light_info(char *filename){
    //Declaring two pointers so that the addresses are not lost while executing
    //the program 
    Node *tempNode = NULL;
    Node *tempHead = NULL;
    //Parameters
    FILE *fptr;
    int i =0;
    char fileInfo[MAXVALUE];
    fptr = fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fptr != NULL){
      while(fgets(fileInfo,sizeof(fileInfo),fptr)!= NULL){
           //Initalizing the value of token as NULL
            char * token = NULL;
            //Mallocs the space for the node 
            tempNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            //Check condition 
            if(tempNode == NULL){
                printf("Sorry cannot create a space on the heap;\n");
                perror("Error at line 61");
                exit(0);               
            }
            printf("NODE : %p \n",tempNode);
        // For the color
            token = strtok(fileInfo,",");
            char*  tempValue= malloc(50);
            tempValue = token;
            printf("%s \n",tempValue);
            printf("Temp value : %p \n",&tempValue);
            tempNode->color = tempValue;
        //Seprating 2 places for the details section 
            tempNode->details = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
        //For the brightness
            token = strtok(NULL,",");
            int tempValueOfBrightness = atoi(token);
            printf("%p \n",&tempValueOfBrightness);
            printf("%d \n",tempValueOfBrightness);
            tempNode->details[0] = &tempValueOfBrightness;
        //For the size 
            token = strtok(NULL,"\n");
            int tempValueOfSize = atoi(token);
            printf("%d \n",tempValueOfSize);
                        printf("%p \n",&tempValueOfSize);
            tempNode->details[1] = &tempValueOfSize;
        //Adding the current address to the head to the node 
            tempNode->next = tempHead;

        //Making the head as the current address
            tempHead = tempNode;
            printf("Temp \n");
        printf("NODE temp : %p \n",tempNode);
        printf("NODE head: %p \n",tempHead);
        i++;

        }
     }else{
         printf("The file cannot be opened. :< \n");
         perror("Error at line 50");
     }
     turnLights(tempHead);
     return tempHead;
}
}
```

I get the following result:

```
NODE : 0x7fffe5462ac0
blue
Temp value : 0x7fffeda80d28
0x7fffeda80d1c
2
0
0x7fffeda80d20
Temp
NODE temp : 0x7fffe5462ac0
NODE head: 0x7fffe5462ac0
NODE : 0x7fffe5462b40
green
Temp value : 0x7fffeda80d28
0x7fffeda80d1c
1
0
0x7fffeda80d20
Temp
NODE temp : 0x7fffe5462b40
NODE head: 0x7fffe5462b40
NODE : 0x7fffe5462bc0
red
Temp value : 0x7fffeda80d28
0x7fffeda80d1c
1
0
0x7fffeda80d20
Temp
NODE temp : 0x7fffe5462bc0
NODE head: 0x7fffe5462bc0
NODE : 0x7fffe5462c40
yellow
Temp value : 0x7fffeda80d28
0x7fffeda80d1c
2
0
0x7fffeda80d20
Temp
NODE temp : 0x7fffe5462c40
NODE head: 0x7fffe5462c40
NODE : 0x7fffe5462cc0
blue
Temp value : 0x7fffeda80d28
0x7fffeda80d1c
1
0
0x7fffeda80d20
Temp
NODE temp : 0x7fffe5462cc0
NODE head: 0x7fffe5462cc0
```

The variable tempValue has the same address in my all run. This is the same for other variables also. As when I run the code, I get only the adresses 0x7fffeda80d28 and 0x7fffeda80d1c. How do I fix this error?

Comment: In your code there is no `temp` variable, there is `tempNode`, `tempHead`, `tempValue`, but no `temp`. Which variable is not changing it's value, exactly? From which statements and exactly which lines from the output are you deducing that? What is the definition of `Node`? Your code is much unreadable, please corent the indentation - indent comments like code. Is this some kind of linked list creation from a comma separated values from a file? Most probably you are asking about why `tempValue = token;` is wrong, you should use `strcpy`. But there are also other problems in your code.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated the code. I could not use strcpy because the struct defines the term as a string literal and not string.

Comment: `tempValue` is a pointer to malloc'ed data. `&tempValue` is an address on the stack.

Comment: @Siguza How can I keep the variables inside the malloced space?

Comment: `the struct defines the term as a string literal and not string` - Sorry, I don't understand that sentence. A [struct definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) defines the structure, it can't "define a term". A [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) is a sequence of characters inside `"`, a string in C is commonly refereed as to sequence of characters ending with a zero byte.

Comment: `keep the variables inside the malloced space` I believe that would be very impractical and almost impossible. You can allocate some storage using malloc and save it to a pointer. The storage for that pointer has to be then allocated on the stack anyway. I believe it would be now a good time to review how pointers and dynamic allocation works in C and what `&` operator does in C. Also read about `strtok`, it just returns pointers to `fileInfo`, so all these pointers are invalid after function returns.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated the code with the definition of the struct\.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the address of variables that are allocated on the stack (pointers).  Those variables will have the same address across function invocations unless you call from somewhere else in the call stack (e.g. calling function or another function).  The addresses of pointers and the addresses they point to aren't the same.

To illustrate the difference (and how stack addresses work)...

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(int x) {

  int* p = &x;

  printf("address of pointer (stack): %p\n", &p);
  printf("pointer (stack): %p\n", p);

  // change pointer to a heap address

  p = malloc(sizeof(int));

  printf("pointer (heap): %p\n", p);
  printf("address of pointer (stack): %p\n", &p);

  free(p);
}

void f2(int x) {

  int y = x;

  f1(x);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int x = 0;

  printf("f1:\n");
  f1(x);

  printf("\nf1 (again):\n");
  f1(x);

  printf("\nf2:\n");
  f2(x);

  return 0;
}
```

output...

```
f1:
address of pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52df0
pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52dfc
pointer (heap): 0x9486b0
address of pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52df0

f1 (again):
address of pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52df0
pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52dfc
pointer (heap): 0x9486b0
address of pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52df0

f2:
address of pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52dd0
pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52ddc
pointer (heap): 0x9486b0
address of pointer (stack): 0x7ffcdcc52dd0
```

Note you're also leaking memory when you allocate `tempValue` but assign the value of `strtok` to it.

```
token = strtok(fileInfo,",");
char*  tempValue= malloc(50);
tempValue = token;
```

Again `tempValue` is a pointer and you're changing the value from a heap address to the pointer returned by `strtok`.  So the address returned from `malloc` is lost and the memory gets leaked (since it can't be returned to the heap using `free`).  Generally, any call to `malloc` should have a corresponding call to `free`, otherwise your program is leaking memory.